# Whitespaces in Access database column

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When i save to database. It always save in the Microsoft Access database with space in front.

what could be the issue.

I have deleted the table and created another. Still the same`
the Saving page has an encryption for passwords.

```
    Dim strPassword As String = txtpassword.Text
    Dim strAlgorigthm As String = "MD5"


    ' Members private to this particular instance of the sandwich class


    'You can also specify these algorights RIPEMD160 or RIPEMD-160 ,SHA or SHA1 ,
    'SHA256 or SHA-256 ,SHA384 or SHA-384,SHA512 or SHA-512
    'SHA1Managed algorithm you must be instantiated directly like this "objAlg = new SHA1Managed()"

    Dim objAlg As HashAlgorithm = Nothing
    'Dim objAlg = New SHA1Managed(strAlgorigthm)
    objAlg = HashAlgorithm.Create(strAlgorigthm)

    ' Convert string to bytes
    Dim objData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(strPassword)

    ' Generate the hash code of password
    Dim objHashBytes As Byte() = objAlg.ComputeHash(objData)
    Dim encryppass As String
    encryppass = BitConverter.ToString(objHashBytes)
    'database connection starts from here

    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\inventory1.accdb")
    cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbltest1;"
    cmd.Connection = cn
    Dim updcmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tbltest1 (userid, fullname, usersname, userspassword) VALUES (' " & txtuser.Text & " ',' " & txtfullname.Text & " ',' " & txtusername.Text & " ',' " & encryppass & " ')")
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    updcmd.Connection = cn
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.InsertCommand = updcmd
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("tbltest1")
    Try
        'cn.Open()
        da.Fill(ds, "tbltest1")
        Dim NewRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("tbltest1").NewRow
        ' Dim countr As Integer = ds.Tables("tblusers").Rows.Count
        NewRow.Item(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim("userid")) = txtuser.Text
        NewRow.Item(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim("fullname")) = txtfullname.Text
        NewRow.Item(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim("usersname")) = txtusername.Text
        NewRow.Item(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim("userspassword")) = encryppass


        ds.Tables("tbltest1").Rows.Add(NewRow)
        'Saving to database            
        da.Update(ds, "tbltest1")
        MsgBox("Information saved successfully", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        cn.Close()
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: In which column?

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: You are inserting a space before and after each value right in your SQL command.  For instance `VALUES (' " & txtuser.Text & " '`.  Note the spaces between the `'` and `"`.  Oh, and as LarsTech said, don't do that.  Use parameters.

Comment: @LarsTech, thank you i will check out how to use parameters,

Comment: @StevenDoggart, thank you for the insight

Comment: issue resolved. I dont know how to mark as answered

Comment: @mantics Since it was just a comment, you can't mark it as the correct answer.  I wrote it up as an actual answer so you can mark it as the correct one now it you so desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting a space before and after each value right in your SQL command. For instance `VALUES (' " & txtuser.Text & " '`. Note the spaces between the `'` and `"`.

Also, as LarsTech said, don't insert data by dynamically appending the values into the SQL command.  Use parameters.